# operator== as default value for std::function

Tags: c++, function, function-pointers

Consider the following function that compares two `vector`s of `T` and verifies that they are the same using `T.operator==` function.

```
template<typename T>
bool Verify(const std::vector<T>& a, const std::vector<T>& b)
{
    if (a.size() != b.size())
        return false;

    for (int ii=0; ii<a.size(); ii++)
        if (!(a[ii] == b[ii]))
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

The problem is that `T` may not contain the `operator==` hence I want to update the `Verify` function so it accepts the comparison function as an argument. This way the user can call the function providing a custom comparison function.

Something like:

```
template<typename T>
bool Verify(const std::vector<T>& a, const std::vector<T>& b, std:function<bool(T,T)> isEqual)
```

The problem is:
Can I set the default value of `isEqual` to be `T.operator==`?

If Yes, how?
If No, what are my alternatives.

Comment: Have you tried to compile it instead of asking us?

Comment: Comparators like any other functions in generic algorithms are usually taken simply by value instead of in a `std::function` wrapper. `template<class T, class F> bool Verify(vector<T> const& a, vector<T> const& b, F);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could set the standard comparison functor [`std::equal_to()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/equal_to) as your default value:

```
template<typename T>
bool Verify( const std::vector<T>& a, 
             const std::vector<T>& b, 
             std::function<bool(const T&,const T&)> isEqual = std::equal_to<T>()
           );
```

Comment: Isn't `equal_to<>` a C++1y feature? (referring to dribeas' edit)

Comment: @DyP as far I know, it was added since C++11, however its easy to write your own equivalent.

Comment: I don't mean `equal_to<T>`, but `equal_to<void>`, providing a generic comparison operator.

Comment: @DyP: So change it to be `equal_to<T>` for C++11 strict compliance, at any rate the original would not work, as `std::equal_to` is the template, and the compiler cannot resolve which specialization is needed.

Answer (score 2):

The general approach taken by the `STL` and others is to pass in the comparison functor as an additional template parameter that is defaulted, but can be overridden.  Here's an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

template <class T, class Compare = std::equal_to<T>>
bool equal(
   const std::vector<T>& lhs,
   const std::vector<T>& rhs,
   Compare comp = {})  // take comparison operator, default where appropriate
{
    if(lhs.size() != rhs.size())
       return false;

    for(size_t x = 0, e = lhs.size(); x < e; ++x)
    {
        if(!comp(lhs[x], rhs[x]))
           return false;
    }

    return true;
}

bool false_equality(int x, int y)
{
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a{1, 2, 3, 4};
    std::vector<int> b{1, 2, 3, 4};

    cout << equal(a, b) << " but " << equal(a, b, false_equality) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Compare comp = {}` is a bit simpler ;)

Comment: It is!  I'm still getting used to incorporating uniform initialization in my code.  Thanks, edited.

Comment: Also, I think you can replace the loop by a `std::equal(begin(lhs), end(lhs), begin(rhs), comp)`.

Comment: Note that in C++1y you can easily let `lhs` and `rhs` be different types (`vector<T>` and `vector<U>`) by using `std::equal_to<>` as your comparator.  In 11 you could write your own.  Oh, and you could simplify the above code by simply having two overloads, one with 2 and one with 3 arguments, and have 2 call 3.

Answer (score 1):

A [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) object can really only be compared to `nullptr`, and can also be constructed using `nullptr`.

This means that you can make the default argument value `nullptr` and compare against that to see if the objects equality function should be used.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer has been given by Manu343726, use the `std::equal_to<>` functor. What is not obvious in that answer is why you don't want to *bind* an operator directly.

In C++ overloaded operators (in most cases) can be implemented both as a member function of the first argument or as a free function. The language is designed to be able to resolve `a == b` by finding whether the given operator is defined one way or another, or maybe neither way (for a fundamental type). On the other hand, when you attempt to obtain the address of an operator manually you need to *know* how the operator is defined (if it is really defined).

With the approach of *setting default value of isEqual to be T.operator==* (the correct syntax would be: `&T::operator==`) you will be able to use the default argument only for those types for which `operator==` is defined as a member function, but it will fail for types where it is defined as a free function.

The same thing occur if you attempt to use the free function version, except that in this case it is even worse, as you don't even know what namespace that operator was defined in (you cannot programatically extract the namespace of a type). Argument dependent lookup does not apply to taking the address of a function

Operators are special in the language, and there are special rules designed to facilitate  the definition (free function/member function) and *use* (ADL) of the operator in code, but those rules don't apply to taking the address of the operator. If you need to bind an operator, the simple answer is to create a helper type that *calls* the operator and then bind that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use function overloading and have both functions. One would take a function as it's last argument while the other will have one less argument. Make the function with one argument less call the other one passing operator== as last argument.